# Bootstrap nav collapse links taking up screen width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navbar

When my nav collapses, the links take up the full width of the screen. How can I make it just the width of the text inside? I've tried targeting the ul and the li css with no luck and an not sure how to approach this. Any suggestions on what style would fix this?

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="nav-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#intro">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#exp">Experience</a></li>
               <li><a href="#skl">Skills</a></li>
              <li><a href="#img-port">Graphic</a></li>
              <li><a href="#vid-port">Video</a></li>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>             
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
#nav-collapse > .nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That works great, I didn't even consider a horizontal nav collapse. I was actually wanting the nav to stay vertical. Do you by chance have a suggestion for a vertical nav collapse?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then `#nav-collapse > .navbar-nav > li > a { display: inline-block; }` should work.